# SQL/Hive query to find the third distinct item bought by all users?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table with the below structure:

```
UserID itemName action
----------------------

1           a           bought

2           b           viewed

3           c           bought

1           b           bought

2           c           bought

1           c           bought

3           b           viewed
```

Now I want to find the third(based on bought count) distinct item bought(action) by **all** users. So could you please help me with the query. Sorry for the bad formatting of the table.

Comment: How do you define the order of items bought? And do you want to identify the '3rd' among all items that each user has bought, or do you want to know for each user which is the '3rd' item they have bought ?

Comment: You would need another field which contains a timestamp. This may be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400712/how-to-do-equivalent-of-limit-distinct)

Comment: @collapsar based on the count i.e the 3rd highest count of item that everyone bought

Comment: @4castle looks different then my case.

Comment: @4castle I want the items that all users bought

Comment: @collapsar edited my question

Comment: I'm confused, can you please edit your question to include some example output?

Comment: @4castle I want the items that all users/everyone bought and out of those I want the 3rd highest bought.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this from your description sounds about right. First select the top 3 by count, grouping by item and sorting by count descending. Then select the top 1 from that set sorting by count ascending. Please keep in mind I am not 100% familiar with HiveSQL, but this SQL code should be very close to standard:

```
SELECT TOP 1 itemName
FROM (
      SELECT TOP 3 itemName, COUNT(*) AS boughtCount
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE action = 'bought'

      GROUP BY itemName
      ORDER BY boughtCount DESC
     )
ORDER BY boughtCount
```

EDIT: As per the precision in the comments:

EDIT 2: This is tested working in MSSQL, might need to adjust some syntax for HiveSQL.

```
SELECT TOP 1 itemId
FROM (
        -- Get the list of the top 3 items that have as many ItemsByUsers entries as distinct userIds 
        -- in the table, group by item and sort by sum of items bought descending.
        SELECT TOP 3 itemId, SUM(boughtCount) AS totalBought
        FROM (
              -- Get a list of the most bought items by item and user
              SELECT itemId, userId, COUNT(*) AS boughtCount
              FROM MyTable
              WHERE action = 'bought'
              GROUP BY itemId, userId
             ) AS ItemCountByUser
        GROUP BY itemId
        HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT userId FROM MyTable) AS UserCount)
        ORDER BY totalBought DESC
     ) AS MostBought
ORDER BY totalBought
```

Comment: You don't need to order the outer select because it only contains one record.

Comment: But this does not guarantee that everyone bought the item that its returning. I want the items that every user bought.

Comment: Right. mostly shown for logic process clarity for the OP.

Comment: i.e userId 1,2,3,... everyone bought it

Comment: So this query would actually be the subselect of yet another select which finds who bought it.

Comment: `SELECT UserID FROM table WHERE itemName IN (SELECT TOP 1 ...)`

Answer (score 0):

My understanding, is you want to display the itemNames that have been bought by ANY user 3 or more times....?

```
SELECT a.itemName FROM
    (SELECT 
        itemName AS itemName,
        sum(action) AS action
    FROM
        (SELECT
            a.itemName as itemName,
            CASE
                WHEN (action = 'bought')
                    THEN (1)
                ELSE (0)
            END AS action
        FROM yourTableName) AS a
    GROUP BY
        itemName) AS a
where action > 2;
```

I have yet to test this out...

Please let me know if this isn't your solution so I can explore other options..

Answer (score 0):

please try the query below to list the itemname that is bought by all users and in the 3rd highest position

`from (
select itemname,count(action) boughtcount from data a 
join 
select distinct userid as id from data  where action='bought' b 
on a.userid=b.id 
where a.action='bought' group by name order by boughtcount desc limit 3) as t select t.itemname limit 1;`